# How to switch between local & remote scripts?

Tags: javascript, include

Let's say I have a bunch of scripts on my server, which are used in my app.

So, my `<head>` contains a bunch of 
`<script src="http://myServer.com/myScript.js"></script>`

If I am developing on `localhost` & don't have net access, I would like to reference those as a bunch of 
`<script src="http://localhost/myScript.js"></script>`   or, even,
`<script src="myScript.js"></script>`

I am very new to JS, is there a standard way to switch between two possible servers for the script file? Google is not my friend on this matter.

Comment: You can use the relative URL in your last `script` section.  Locally, though, I think IE blocks you depending on security settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just dynamically load the script and add it to the document, based on whether you're accessing the page from `localhost` or not, as such:

```
<script> 

var script = document.createElement("script");

if (/localhost/.test(document.location.hostname)) {
    script.setAttribute("src", "./myScript.js");
} else {
    script.setAttribute("src", "http://www.myServer.com/myScript.js");
}

document.body.appendChild(script);

</script>
```

Comment: +1 OIC, I didn't think of that. Is it a standard or best practise then?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a standard or not, but I've done similar things multiple times in enterprise production sites to make it easier to do stuff in development vs. production environments (albeit normally with AMD and not directly injecting it into the document body)

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is if the JS is required for the app to function, you're providing a worse experience in production since the app would be dysfunctional until this JS ran (whenever the browser decides to do so) whereas the other way the browser would block until the JS loaded.

Comment: This is true, and like I said, I don't normally do it exactly like this in production apps, I normally do it in an AMD statement, and generally only with modules. That being said, if it is for something like jQuery, your answer would be better hands down.

Answer (score 1):

In situations where I'd like to be able to continue development while offline on a webapp that has resources pulled from CDNs, I've used fallbacks.

For example, for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!window.jQuery) {
        document.write('<script src="./js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
        console.error('jQuery from CDN not available - reverting to local copy');
    }
</script>
```

Or for BootstrapJS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!(typeof $().modal == 'function')) {
        document.write('<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>');
        console.error('Bootstrap JS from CDN not available - reverting to local copy');
    }
</script>
```

Or for FontAwesome:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
...
<span class="fa hide" id="faChecker"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($('#faChecker').css('fontFamily') !== 'FontAwesome') {
        $('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font-awesome.min.css" \/>').appendTo('head');
        console.error('FontAwesome CSS from CDN not available - reverting to local copy');
    }
</script>
```

Similarly, you can make use of some variable that `myScript.js` would set and if it's not set, use the local fallback version.

This has the added benefit of helping prevent your site from malfunctioning if a CDN goes down.

Comment: +1 Yes, I saw that approach elsewhere. But doesn't it rely on you knowing one unique thing from every library, so that you can check for it & fallback if not loaded?  I am feeling uncertain about this - I might go either way. It depends if I can find a better solution. Thanks for reminding me of it, though.

Comment: @Mawg, yes. This is a disadvantage; however, in my experience, it's not too difficult to find one. It's especially simple if you have control of the JS and it's just from an external source rather than some CDN. In that case, just add a version marker somewhere and check for that.